# Multiple observations – Wilcoxon matched pairs test R

Tags: r, data-visualization, paired-data

I’m dealing with matched pairs graphs in R but I’m not sure there’s a way to keep my dataset as it is and make a graph out of that. Let me explain better.
Let’s say I have to take into account 3 subjects’ temperature (A,B,C) in two conditions (grooming and feeding) . Here a similar dataset to mine:

```
   event   id     temperature 
1 grooming  A     30
2 grooming  A     31
3 grooming  B     32
4 grooming  C     31
5 grooming  C     31
6 grooming  C     30
7 feeding   A     29
8 feeding   A     28
9 feeding   A     29
10 feeding   B     30
11 feeding   B     28
12 feeding   C     28
```

As you can see, the number of observations per individual is different across the 2 conditions and most importantly, grooming and feeding data were collected in two separate moments (those 2 event are not consecutive). In my opinion the only way to use a matched pairs graph would be to calculate the mean per individual per each condition and plot that. Do you know if there’s a method to keep multiple observations and plot those?

Also, I’m struggling to get the right codes to plot a matched pairs graph using a scatter plot, not boxplots. How can I modify the following codes in order to get a **Wilcoxon** matched paired test with scatter plot?

`library("ggpubr")`

```
 ggboxplot(meanbr, x = "event", y = "temperature", 
 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
 order = c("feeding", "grooming"),
 ylab = "temperature", xlab = "event")
```

`install.packages("PairedData")`

```
  control <- subset(meant,event == "feeding", temperature,
             drop = TRUE)
  grooming<- subset(meant,event == "grooming", temperature,
            drop = TRUE)
  library(PairedData)
  pd <- paired(feeding, grooming)
  plot(pd, type = "profile") + theme_bw()
  res <- t.test(temperature ~ event, data = meant, paired = TRUE)
  res
```

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.